# how to change BorderColor of Image programmatically in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't change BorderColor of Image programmatically in asp.net

```
Image stamp = new Image();
stamp.BorderColor = HexColor("#F2F0E1");
stamp.BorderColor = White;
stamp.BorderColor = "White";
stamp.BorderColor = ConsoleColor.White;
stamp.BorderColor = Color.White;
stamp.BorderColor = System.Drawing.White;

stamp.CssClass = "stamp";
```

These all are NOT working. Please help. CssClass is also NOT working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First on your properties set your BorderStyle to Inset. Or you can do this on your aspx code as shown below then use  Image1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

.aspx

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Penguins.jpg" 
    BorderStyle="Inset" Height="599px" Width="457px"  />
</body>
</html>
```

.cs

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Image1.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

    }
```

Comment: Problem solved. Many thanks. But how can I use CssClass in the code behind file? Any tips, please?

Comment: Image1.Attributes["class"] = "myclass";  on your Site.css .myclass{ border-color:Black;}

Answer (score 0):

remove all the border color sets, leave only the setting of the css class and make sure the css file is loaded, if you still have problems with it, start by unloading the css file ( maybe you run over the class ) and redefine it in line at the markup, should work fine.

edit, try to use this in the CSS

```
border:5px solid red;
```

Comment: But I need to know how to set BorderColor property and use CssClass in the code behind file.

Comment: do you know how to use firebug or dev tools of browsers? if yes try to modify the properties and see what the asp.net translate it to. if not try to read about firebug a bit and learn how to use it, its a front end developer best friend